# Python logging levels are behaving inconsistently

Tags: python, logging

I can't understand why the following code does not produce my debug message even though effective level is appropriate (output is just `10`)

```
import logging

l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.debug("Debug Mess!")
l.error(l.getEffectiveLevel())
```

while when I add this line after the import: `logging.debug("Start...")`

```
import logging

logging.debug("Start...")
l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.debug("Debug Mess!")
l.error(l.getEffectiveLevel())
```

it produces following output:

```
DEBUG:root:Debug Mess!
ERROR:root:10
```

so even though "Start..." is not shown, it starts to log. Why?

It's on Python 3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top-level `logging.debug(..)` call calls the [`logging.basicConfig()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) for you if no handlers have been configured yet on the root logger.

Because using a call to `logging.getLogger().debug()` does *not* trigger that call, you don't see any output because there are no handlers to show the output on.

The Python 3 version of `logger` does have a [`logging.lastResort` handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort), used for when no logging configuration exists, but this handler is configured to only show messages of level `WARNING` and up, which is why you see your `ERROR` level message (`10`) printed to STDERR, but not your `DEBUG` level message. In Python 2 you would get the message *No handlers could be found for logger "root"* printed instead, just once for the first attempt to log anything. I'd not rely on the `lastResort` handler however; instead properly configure your logging hierarchy with a decent handler configured for your own needs.

Either call `logging.basicConfig()` yourself, or manually add a handler on the root logger:

```
l = logging.getLogger()
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

The above basically does the same thing as a `logging.basicConfig()` call with no further arguments. The `StreamHandler()` created this way logs to STDERR and does not further filter on the message level. Note that a `logging.basicConfig()` call can also set the logging level for you.

Comment: what is the best practice to inherit the log level from the caller yet be able to have unittest with logs withing the module?

Answer (score 0):

The root logger(default logger, top level) and all other logger's default log level is `warning`(order 3) in all 5 log levels: `debug` < `info` < `warning` < `error` < `fatal` in order.

So at your first `logging.debug('starting...')`, you haven't set the root log level to `debug` as following code and you can't get the `starting...`output.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('starting...')
```

[see python logging HOW TO for detail](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)